# Python to insert records into a log file which is used by another batch job

Tags: python, batch-file

I am facing a peculiar problem. 
I have a batch script that uses a log file named logfile.txt. Essentially this batch job is nothing but a series of `xcopy` and python file running like below:

```
xcopy /I "source" "destination /D" >> D:\logfile\logfile.txt
xcopy /I "source" "destination /D" >> D:\logfile\logfile.txt
....
cd C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
pyhton D:\python_files\py_file_1.py >> D:\logfile\logfile.txt
python D:\python_files\py_file_2.py >> D:\logfile\logfile.txt
....
```

Now two things I want to mention. And my questions are aligned to these two points.

1. While I can see the `xcopy` related stuffs are being shown in logfile
   (i.e. number of files copied), there is no log entry for running
   python job. Why so?
2. I have another python script (as shown below) which fills up another .txt file named `py_log.txt` in case any error happens while running the above py files. In case of no errors, a standard line is inserted. I want to insert these error entry or a standard entry to the batch `logfile.txt`.

   ```
   lines = []
   with open('py_log.txt','r') as f_in:
        z = str(f_in)
        lines.append(z)
   with open('logfile.txt', 'a') as f_out:    
        if len(lines) > 1:
            f_out.write('\n'+lines) # Error Entry if Any
        else:
            f_out.write('\n'+'Data load job has been completed at {0}'.format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M')
   ```

Problem is, when I schedule the above python script on Task Scheduler, it doesn't insert any text to the logfile.txt. When I run this on a standalone basis, it is working fine.

Why the above script is not able to write when put the same on Task Scheduler. What am I missing?

Comment: `xcopy /I "source" "destination /D"` is supposed to be `xcopy /I "source" "destination" /D`, right?

Comment: ...and `pyhton` is supposed to be `python`, right?

Comment: Yes...sorry typo.

Answer (score 0):

[My suggestion is to use the python built-in logging module](https://realpython.com/python-logging/)

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? If so, then how to get the contents of `py_log.txt` into the `logging.info()`? Or did you mean I should directly use the `logfile.txt` with `logging.basicConfig(filename='logfile.txt' ,level=logging.WARNING)`? Please clarify

Comment: You should directly use the logfile.txt with logging.basicConfig(filename='logfile.txt' ,level=logging.WARNING). I've tried the way you are doing it and it's a mess, always a different error coming up. I've tried this solution and everything worked perfect

Comment: But how do I gather the content of `py_log.txt` and use the same in `logging`? This is important as it contains error messages.

Comment: Also `logging` doesn't support `.txt` file types. It only recognizes `.log` file.

Comment: You can create a temporary file convert log to txt and via versa and the you delete the file. I also think that Python has something built int for temporary files